# How can I mimic full outer join in mysql with multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: A and B.

Table A has the following set-up:

| ID | date | location | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 10000 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 | 1 | 10000 |
| 3 | 2022-01-04 | 1 | 10000 |
| ... | .... | 2 | .... |

So there is no data for for the location `1` at the date `2022-01-03`.

Table B has the following set-up:

| ID | date | location | budget |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 10000 |
| 2 | 2022-01-03 | 1 | 10000 |
| 3 | 2022-01-04 | 1 | 10000 |
| ... | .... | 2 | .... |

So there is no record for location `1` for the date `2022-01-02`.

I am trying to join the tables together to get the following output

| location | sales | budget |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30000 | 30000 |
| 2 | ... | ... |

So I can group it on location and get `| location ABC | sales 123 | budget 123 |`, which is a sum of all the dates grouped, but also joined the 2 tables together on date and location.

The query I currently have now is as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(A.sales) AS sales, A.restaurant
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.date = B.date AND A.location= B.location
WHERE A.date between ? AND ? 
GROUP BY A.location
UNION
SELECT SUM(B.budget) AS budget, B.restaurant
FROM A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON A.date = B.date AND A.restaurant = B.restaurant
WHERE B.date between ? AND ?  
GROUP BY B.restaurant
```

I've tried different types of joins and unions and ended up with a query as suggested in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-can-i-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql) to mimic a full outer join. However, with this query I get the following output:

| location | column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30000 |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |
| 1 | 30000 |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |

These sums are correct, but are not in 2 separate columns 'sales' and 'budget'.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: "*These sums are correct but not in 2 separate columns 'sales' and 'budget'.*" - What do you mean by this?...are you trying to net the `sales` against the `budget`?

Comment: Yes indeed, but now to are added on new rows but I want them represented in separate  columns

Comment: Eh?  " joined the 2 tables together on date and location" -- But your desired output does not involve "date"??

Comment: Yes, dates to get the sum within a certain timeframe but the sum itself is the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `UNION` clause the alignment of the columns in each unioned dataset defines the order of those columns in the final result set.

Since you don't want the `sales` and `budget` data points to be in the same column, you can just un-align them and add placeholder default values in the other dataset like so:

```
SELECT 0 AS budget, SUM(A.sales) AS sales, A.restaurant
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.date = B.date AND A.location= B.location
WHERE A.date between ? AND ? 
GROUP BY A.location
UNION
SELECT SUM(B.budget) AS budget, 0 AS sales, B.restaurant
FROM A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON A.date = B.date AND A.restaurant = B.restaurant
WHERE B.date between ? AND ?  
GROUP BY B.restaurant
```

Then to get the final results you want, you'll want to do one more grouping again on `location` in a subquery or CTE to aggregate the different sides of the `UNION` into a single row like so:

```
SELECT location, SUM(sales) AS sales, SUM(budget) AS budget
FROM 
(
    SELECT 0 AS budget, SUM(A.sales) AS sales, A.location
    FROM A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.date = B.date AND A.location= B.location
    WHERE A.date between ? AND ? 
    GROUP BY A.location
    UNION
    SELECT SUM(B.budget) AS budget, 0 AS sales, B.restaurant
    FROM A
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON A.date = B.date AND A.restaurant = B.restaurant
    WHERE B.date between ? AND ?  
    GROUP BY B.restaurant
) Results
GROUP BY location
```

Note I think I fixed a typo in your first dataset of the `UNION` clause by changing `A.restaurant` to `A.location`.

Comment: Sorry I cannot mark as correct because of my reputation but this works. Thanks so much for the explanation!

Comment: @user3069332 No problem, glad it works! There's no limitation on marking answers as correct (it's just the ✔️ checkmark button), you just probably can't upvote it which is fine. But no worries either way.

Comment: I’ve clicked to indicate it as correct, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

J.D. has explained how to arrange the different aggregates in different columns in the end result.  Let me address another issue.

It seems to me that for your problem, not only can you do without a full join, emulated or real, you actually do not need *any* join at all.  You want aggregates per location from one table, and aggregates per location from the other table.  And you want the aggregates from the different tables to be on the same row if they are for the same location.

So this is how you can go about it.

1. Get the aggregates from one table:

   ```
   SELECT
     location
   , SUM(sales) AS sales
   FROM
     A
   WHERE
     date BETWEEN ? AND ?
   GROUP BY
     location
   ```

   You should get something like this:

   | location | sales |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 30000 |
   | 2 | ... |
2. Get the aggregates from the other table:

   ```
   SELECT
     restaurant
   , SUM(budget) AS budget
   FROM
     B
   WHERE
     date BETWEEN ? AND ?
   GROUP BY
     restaurant
   ```

   Output:

   | restaurant | budget |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 30000 |
   | 2 | ... |
3. `UNION` the two results, applying J.D.'s suggestion of using placeholders:

   ```
   SELECT
     location
   , SUM(sales) AS sales
   , 0          AS budget
   FROM
     A
   WHERE
     date BETWEEN ? AND ?
   GROUP BY
     location

   UNION ALL

   SELECT
     restaurant
   , 0
   , SUM(budget)
   FROM
     B
   WHERE
     date BETWEEN ? AND ?
   GROUP BY
     restaurant
   ```

   The output in this case should look like this:

   | location | sales | budget |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 30000 | 0 |
   | 2 | ... | ... |
   | ... | ... | ... |
   | 1 | 0 | 30000 |
   | 2 | ... | ... |
   | ... | ... | ... |
4. Now all you need is to aggregate the data once more over the combined set:

   ```
   SELECT
     location
   , SUM(sales ) AS sales
   , SUM(budget) AS budget
   FROM
     (
       SELECT
         location
       , SUM(sales) AS sales
       , 0          AS budget
       FROM
         A
       WHERE
         date BETWEEN ? AND ?
       GROUP BY
         location

       UNION ALL

       SELECT
         restaurant
       , 0
       , SUM(budget)
       FROM
         B
       WHERE
         date BETWEEN ? AND ?
       GROUP BY
         restaurant
     ) AS derived
   ;
   ```

   And that should give you the expected output of

   | location | sales | budget |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 30000 | 30000 |
   | 2 | ... | ... |